# Функция не возвращает значение (return не работает как надо)

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте.

Объявление структуры прямоугольника.

```
typedef struct {int ax; int ay; int cx; int cy;} rectangle;
```

Хранит в себе координаты точек прямоугольника.

---

Прототип функции использующей структуру

```
rectangle paint(rectangle A, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2);
```

Функция рисует прямоугольник на **PaintBox'е**

---

Тело ф-ии

```
rectangle paint(rectangle A, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{

y1=400-y1;
y2=400-y2;

A.ax=x1;
A.ay=y1;

A.cx=x2;
A.cy=y2;

Form1->PaintBox1->Canvas->Pen->Color=clBlack;
Form1->PaintBox1->Canvas->MoveTo(A.ax,A.ay);
Form1->PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(A.ax,A.cy);
Form1->PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(A.cx,A.cy);
Form1->PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(A.cx,A.ay);
Form1->PaintBox1->Canvas->LineTo(A.ax,A.ay);

return A;}
```

`x1=StrToInt(Edit1->Text);` **и т.д для x2,y1,y2**

Проблема в том, что **return A** хоть и возвращает значения структуры **А**, в виде:

```
    A.ax=x1;
    A.ay=y1;

    A.cx=x2;
    A.cy=y2;
```

Но как только ф-я заканчивает свою работу, значения в структуре **А** обнуляются, а нужно чтобы они так и оставались равны **x1,x2,y1,y2**. Они **должны** быть равны, но что то тут не так)

В чем тут дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В прототипе следует использовать ССЫЛКУ на А или адрес А, чтобы компилятор не создавал копию прямоугольника, которую он сам же и разрушает при выходе из ф-ции.

```
void paint(rectangle &A, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2);// или
void paint(rectangle *A, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2);
```

А еще лучше сделать эту ф-цию public-методом класса (структуры)

Comment: Спасибо) Вариант с &A работает) с 8 нет чето(

Comment: Вообще говоря, к моменту рисования прямоугольник (экземпляр) уже должен существовать вместе со своими углами.